# python string retrieve the value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can some one please help me how to get the `Value` for `Key: 'labelnumber'` from string below?

Tried json manipulation and eval but no luck.

```
{'Value': 'infotech', 'Key': 'company'},{'Value': 'printing', 'Key': 'LineofBusiness'},{'Value': 'Non-Prod', 'Key': 'Environment'},{'Value': '1234-5623', 'Key': 'labelnumber'},{'Value': 'globalinfra', 'Key': 'ApplicationName'}
```

I need to get the value of "labelnumber" key which is "1234-5623"

This string comes from a dictionary

```
d1 = {'Name': 'Maintags', 'Type': 'String', 'Value': "{'Value': 'infotech', 'Key': 'company'},{'Value': 'printing', 'Key': 'LineofBusiness'},{'Value': 'Non-Prod', 'Key': 'Environment'},{'Value': '1234-5623', 'Key': 'labelnumber'},{'Value': 'globalinfra', 'Key': 'ApplicationName'}"}

>>>print(d1)

    {'Name': 'Maintags', 'Type': 'String', 'Value': "{'Value': 'infotech', 'Key': 'company'},{'Value': 'printing', 'Key': 'LineofBusiness'},{'Value': 'Non-Prod', 'Key': 'Environment'},{'Value': '1234-5623', 'Key': 'labelnumber'},{'Value': 'globalinfra', 'Key': 'ApplicationName'}"}

>>>print(type(d1))

    <class 'dict'>

>>>print(d1["Value"])

    {'Value': 'infotech', 'Key': 'company'},{'Value': 'printing', 'Key': 'LineofBusiness'},{'Value': 'Non-Prod', 'Key': 'Environment'},{'Value': '1234-5623', 'Key': 'labelnumber'},{'Value': 'globalinfra', 'Key': 'ApplicationName'}
```

Comment: What you've shown is not valid JSON because it does not use double quotes.  Is `string1` a variable that contains this value? If so, I suspect it's a list, can you please add the output of `print(type(string1))` to your question?

Comment: It is not clear what you've shown here and what you've tried. Please provide a clear [mre]

Comment: Updated with complete information.. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So, you dont have JSON here... The proper solution would be to fix how you create `d1` (why does the first Value need to be a string? Can it be a list?). Otherwise, you could use a regex grouping to find each `{'Value': ?, 'Key': ?}` object (since splitting on commas wouldn't work either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1 = {'Name': 'Maintags', 'Type': 'String', 'Value': "{'Value': 'infotech', 'Key': 'company'},{'Value': 'printing', 'Key': 'LineofBusiness'},{'Value': 'Non-Prod', 'Key': 'Environment'},{'Value': '1234-5623', 'Key': 'labelnumber'},{'Value': 'globalinfra', 'Key': 'ApplicationName'}"}
my_values_dict = {d['Key']:d['Value'] for d in eval(d1['Value'])}
print(my_values_dict['labelnumber'])
```

output: `1234-5623`

Use eval() to get a tuple of dictionaries, loop through it to turn it in a single dictionary, access the key you need.

Comment: Thank you so much JLeno46.. your solution is working great. Appreciate your help !